# My Java zipped file not supported in Junzip C program

Tags: c, zip

I have written a Java program to zip files and to unzip them in an unzipping C program called Junzip.
https://github.com/jokkebk/JUnzip. I'm able to unzip the file using 7zip file extractor. But when using C Junzip, its not unzipping.
But when I'm unzipping the file, which was zipped using normal file compressor, I'm able to unzip it using the same jUnzip library.

Answer (score 1):

Author of the JUnzip library here, just came across this question. Did I understand correctly that .zip files made by your program unzip correctly with 7zip, but not with JUnzip, whereas JUnzip seems to be able to uncompress .zip files made by others?

Without further info, it's hard to say if there's a .zip feature you are using that JUnzip does not support, or if there's a bug in JUnzip. One possible reason is that the library and junzip.exe only supports a limited set of compression methods, namely Deflate that is supported by zlib library it uses. The code base is rather small so you could probably add a few debug statements to see where it goes wrong.

You can check out https://codeandlife.com/2014/01/01/unzip-library-for-c/ for some details regarding JUnzip.